# Can taxonomy terms contain special characters e.g. ampersands, apostrophes and dashes?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

What characters are legal in taxonomy terms in Drupal 7? I haven't been able to find a list of illegal characters. Does this mean all characters are legal? I am particularly interested in knowing if ampersands, apostrophes and dashes are safe to use. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are safe to use, however you may have issues with your url paths. so in your url if you have a term Theology & Scripture", it becomes this: 'theology%20%2526%20scripture. This kind of urls are not good for search engine optimisation.

You can however use the [pathauto module](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto), to correct this issue.

> The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for
>   various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without
>   requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. This allows you
>   to have URL aliases like /category/my-node-title instead of /node/123.
>   The aliases are based upon a "pattern" system that uses tokens which
>   the administrator can change.